# ZF2 - Download xls show two empty lines in the downloaded sheet

Tags: excel, download, zend-framework2

I am using streams to download the excel file. Please find the code below

```
 $response = new \Zend\Http\Response\Stream();
 $response->setStream(fopen($myfile, 'r'));
 $response->setStatusCode(200);

 $headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
 $headers->addHeaderLine("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8")
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=my.xls')
        ->addHeaderLine( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" )
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', filesize($myfile));
 $response->setHeaders($headers);
```

The file generated is proper but when the same file I am enforcing the user to download there are two empty lines coming in the downloaded excel file. I did some researching and thought may it's http version and header lines but I think it's not because if I try otherwise I get those two empty line in start of excel report.

Please note there are no empty space in the start of the content.

Any idea ?? why it's so?

Answer (score 1):

Mind the streamed response does in fact not really provide a stream context to the client. It just [buffers the stream internally](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Response/Stream.php#L229-L235) and sends out the response in one go.

That being said, I have created a controller plugin to send attachments from a file path or directly with the binary data addressed to a variable. It's in my common [Soflomo\Common](https://github.com/Soflomo/Common) library. I haven't had the issues you described and I use [some more headers than you do](https://github.com/Soflomo/Common/blob/master/src/Common/Controller/Plugin/Attachment.php#L88-L99).

Tell me if that piece of code works for you. One of the differences is you use the size of the original file as the size of the response. I am not sure, as this might cause an indifference with the cached streamed response. Try to just grab the contents and do a `strlen()` on this content.

Comment: $content="hello"; $response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setContent($content);
$response->getHeaders()
->addHeaderLine('Pragma', 'public')
->addHeaderLine('Cache-control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
    ->addHeaderLine('Cache-control', 'private')
                 ->addHeaderLine("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8")
                 ->addHeaderLine( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" )
                 ->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', strlen($content))
                 ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=my.xls');

Comment: in exccel sheet it is also coming after 2 empty rows.... can you share how can I debug the issue ..

Comment: You can try to compare the two files: one on your server and the one you download. If there is any difference, you know where it comes from. It's easier to debug text files, like simple .txt or more comparable to excel, .csv. Excel is a binary format, but does the problem occur with .csv files too?

Comment: with txt it is working but with CSV or xls it is giving extra two lines in the downloaded file. Any other suggestion...